# "Pasting" raw contents of a yaml file in Liquid

Tags: file, yaml, jekyll, liquid

I have a `yaml` configuration file that looks something similar to this:

```yaml
# This file is placed at _data/snakemake_config.yaml

control: "controls/master_control.csv"
results_dir: "results"
generation:
  genome_save_dir: "genome/star"
  gtf_file: "genome/Homo_sapiens.105.gtf"
```

I'd like to output the contents of this file on the screen as a sort of "live-updater", so if I change something in the config file (say, updating `control:` to `control: "controls/new_default_file.csv"`), its changes will also be reflected in the Jekyll/Liquid markdown page. This is what I've done so far, but it places an extra newline on every line:

````
{% comment %}
This can be under index.md
Note: indentation is intentional, read further for reasoning
{% endcomment %}

```yaml
{% for line in site.data.snakemake_config %}
{% if line[0] == "generation" %} 
{{- line[0] }}:
   {% for element in site.data.snakemake_config.generation %}
   {{- element[0] -}}: {{ element[1] }}
   {% endfor %}
{% else %}
{{- line[0] -}}: {{ line[1] }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```
````

This is the output I get:

```yaml
control: controls/master_control.csv


results_dir: results


generation:
   genome_save_dir: genome/star
   gtf_file: genome/Homo_sapiens.105.gtf
```

I'm able to remove a few of the newlines by placing various lines of the Liquid code on the same line, but then readability is extremely difficult (not to mention maintaining in the future). Even now, the Liquid portion isn't easily readable - no indentation on nested for/if statements, etc.

Ideally, I would effectively "copy and paste" the contents of the `snakemake_config.yaml` file info `index.md`

Does anyone have an idea on how I can go about doing this? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture to intake the raw data, and then use that variable. Based on [this answer](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/how-can-i-display-a-raw-html-or-md-file-without-jekyll-processing-it-so-that-a-visitor-can-see-the-raw-html-contents/5771/2) (switched to `<pre>` for the example):

```
{%- capture rawContent -%}
  {%- include_relative _data/snakemake_config.yaml -%}
{%- endcapture -%}
<pre>
{{rawContent}}
</pre>
```